# No se pueden eliminar los productos con el mismo botón que los agrega al carrito (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, botón, eventos, delete, events

El código funciona y al hacer click en confirmar compra los productos se agregan al carrito pero cuando se hace click de nuevo en el mismo botón para eliminar el o los productos seleccionados, salta un error por consola que evita que se haga tal acción.

El error por consola es:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
at deletebtns (main.js:64)
at confirm (main.js:46)
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

¿Esto ocurre por ser el mismo botón para agregar/eliminar o por otra causa?

No encuentro la solución para que funcione adecuadamente...

```
class Producto {
    constructor() {

    }

}


const prods = arraySet();

let price = 0;
let prodNum;

/*------------------------------------ FUNCIONES ------------------------------------*/

function arraySet() {
    const prods = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        prods[i] = new Producto();
        prods[i].id = i;
        prods[i].cantidad = 0;
        prods[i].nombre = document.getElementById(i).innerHTML;
        prods[i].precio = parseInt(document.getElementById("p" + i).innerHTML);

    }

    return prods;
}

function addToCart(prods, btn) {

    let prod = document.createElement("div");

    prod.innerHTML = `<h4>${prods[btn].nombre}</h4>
                      <h5> ${prods[btn].precio}</h5>`;

    document.body.appendChild(prod);

}

function confirm() {

    let price = setPrice();
    deletebtns();

    let priceView = document.createElement("div");

    priceView.innerHTML = `<h5 style="color: rgb(34, 34, 233)">Precio final (envío incluido): </h5>
                           <h6 style="color: rgb(34, 34, 233)> $${price}</h6>`;

    document.body.appendChild(priceView);

}

function deletebtns() {

    btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary");
    tds = document.getElementsByClassName("tdb");

    for (let i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {

        tds.item(i).removeChild(btns.item(0));

    }

}

function setPrice() {

    let prs = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");

    let finalp = 0;

    for (const j of prs) {

        finalp += parseInt(j.innerHTML);

    }

    finalp += (finalp * 0.05);

    return finalp;

}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Indumentaria Urbana</h1>
    <hr>

    <table class="table">

        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio ($)</th>
                <th scope="col">Carrito</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td id="0">Zapatillas Nike</td>
                <td id="p0">100</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addToCart(prods, 0)'>Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="1">Botines Air Jordan</td>
                <td id="p1">250</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addToCart(prods, 1)'>Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="2">Zapatillas Urban Light</td>
                <td id="p2">25</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addToCart(prods, 2)'>Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="3">Zapatillas Addidas</td>
                <td id="p3">60</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addToCart(prods, 3)'>Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="4">Gorra Stussy</td>
                <td id="p4">20</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick='addToCart(prods, 4)'>Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <div></div>

    <section>
        <h3>Carrito</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm" onclick='confirm()'>Confirmar compra</button>
    </section>

    <section>

        <p>Nombre</p>
        <p>Precio ($)</p>

    </section>



    <hr>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Te aconsejo usar JavaScript para poner evento en los botones de la misma clase: `window.onload=function(){var btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary"); for ( let i=0; i<btn.length; i++ ){ btn[i].addEventListener("click",function(){addToCart(prods,i);} );} }`. Para que cuando tengas que añadir mas botones no tengas que añadir el evento con el indice correspondiente. Nota: No use `var` porque acabo de tener problema con ese operador, por lo que cambié a `let`.

Comment: No entendí el comentario @DanielBriceño pues me fije y en el código que publiqué la función deletebtns( ) hace referencia a la misma clase btn btn-primary y de hecho no sé si ese código que me pasaste es para consumirlo de cual o qué manera o que parte hay que eliminar en el código y sustituirlo por este... es confuso para mi la verdad... si puedes ser más profundo y detallista en tu comentario te lo agradecería

Comment: comienza separando el código php, html, css y javascript en archivos diferentes. tu codigo php no tiene los tag de apertura y cierre.

Comment: cual es el contenido de main.js???

Comment: main.js es justo el código que he publicado al principio de post, es decir, acá hay dos códigos: el de javascript que es el del archivo main,js por el que me preguntas y el de html que es el archivo index.tml

Comment: El codigo  es para que cada vez que insertes un nuevo boton de `agregar al carrito.` no tengas que preocuparte por colocarle el evento correspondiente. Lo que hace es solo agregar este evento: `onclick='addToCart(prods,1)' ` a todos los elementos button con class `btn btn-primary` sin que tengas que escribirlo a mano.

Comment: ¿Como hiciste para eliminar el elemento, hay solo sale cuando agregas el elemento?

Comment: Eliminar el elemento se hacía pulsando en el mismo botón de confirmar compra... pero acabo de ver tu respuesta tan completa... excelente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He hecho varios cambios a tu codigo JavaScript y conseguí este resultado:

```HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Ejercicio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Indumentaria Urbana</h1>
    <hr>

    <table class="table">

        <thead>

            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
                <th scope="col">Precio ($)</th>
                <th scope="col">Carrito</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td id="0">Zapatillas Nike</td>
                <td id="p0">100</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="1">Botines Air Jordan</td>
                <td id="p1">250</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="2">Zapatillas Urban Light</td>
                <td id="p2">25</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="3">Zapatillas Addidas</td>
                <td id="p3">60</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="4">Gorra Stussy</td>
                <td id="p4">20</td>
                <td class="tdb"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Añadir al
                        carrito</button></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>

    </table>

    <div></div>

    <section>
        <h3>Carrito</h3>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm" onclick='confirm()'>Confirmar compra</button>
    </section>

    <section>

        <p>Nombre</p>
        <p>Precio ($)</p>

    </section>



    <hr>
    <div id="container">
        <!--Generado por JavaScript.-->
    </div>
    <script>
          class Producto {
              constructor( id,cantidad,name,precio ){
                  this.id=id;
                  this.cantidad=cantidad;
                  this.name=name;
                  this.precio=precio;
            }
          }
        // Vars global and contans.
        var prods;
        var price = 0;
        var prodNum;
        const id_father="container";
        //Insertamos el evento a todos los botones de la clase btn btn-primary.
        window.onload=function(){
            let btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary");
            for ( let i=0; i<btn.length; i++ ){
                btn[i].onclick=function(){
                   addToCart(prods,i);
                }
             }
             //Iniciamos la variable prods con una lista de la clase Producto();
             prods= arraySet();
          }
        
        /*------------------------------------ FUNCIONES ------------------------------------*/
        function arraySet() {
            const prods = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                prods[i] = new Producto(i,
                                                              0,
                                                              document.getElementById(i).innerHTML,
                                                               parseInt(document.getElementById("p" + i).innerHTML)
                                                              );
            }
            return prods;
        }

        function addToCart(prods, btn) {
            let prod = document.createElement("div");
            let btn_this=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[btn]
            let father=document.getElementById(id_father);
    
            prod.innerHTML = `<h4>${prods[btn].name}</h4>
                                                <h5> ${prods[btn].precio}</h5>`;
            //Le mostramos al usuario que tiene la opcion de quitar el elemento del carrito.
            btn_this.innerHTML="Quitar elemento del carrito.";
            
            father.appendChild(prod);
            
            //Cambiamos la llamada al evento para poder eliminar el elemento del carrito.
            btn_this.onclick=function(){
                deletecOfCart( prod,btn );
            }
        }
        function deletecOfCart( element,btn ){
            let this_btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[btn];
            //Eliminamos el elemento de la lista que no se quiere.
            document.getElementById( id_father ).removeChild( element );
            
            this_btn.innerHTML="añadir al carrito.";
            this_btn.onclick=function(){
                 addToCart(prods,btn);
            }
        }
        function confirm() {
            let priceView = document.createElement("div");
            let price = setPrice();
            deletebtns();
            priceView.innerHTML = `<h5 style="color: rgb(34, 34, 233)">Precio final (envío incluido): </h5>
                                                          <h6 style="color: rgb(34, 34, 233)> $${price}</h6>`;

            document.body.appendChild(priceView);

        }
        function deletebtns() {
            btns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary");
            tds = document.getElementsByClassName("tdb");
            for (let i = 0; i < prods.length; i++) {
                 tds.item(i).removeChild(btns.item(0));
            }
        }
        function setPrice() {
            let prs = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");
            let finalp = 0;
            for (var j of prs) {
                finalp += parseInt(j.innerHTML);
             }
             finalp += (finalp * 0.05);
             return finalp;
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

### Los cambios que hice:

Hice que cuando se precione el boton de complar se cambie el texto del boton:
`btn_this.innerHTML="Quitar elemento del carrito.";`. Nota: `btn_this` es el boton actualmente pulsado.

Tambien le cambié la funcion que el boton ya pulsado va a llamar: `btn_this.onclick=function(){deletecOfCart( prod,btn );}`. La funcion `deletecOfCart(element,btn);`. Hace lo contrario a la funcion: `addToCart(prods,btn);`. Lo que hace es: Eliminar el elemento pasado y cambia el texto del boton para retaurarlo, tambien regresa el evento del boton seleccionado a la funcion por defecto:

#### addToCart:

```JavaScript
function addToCart(prods, btn) {
     let prod = document.createElement("div");
     let btn_this=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[btn]
     let father=document.getElementById(id_father);
    
     prod.innerHTML = `<h4>${prods[btn].name}</h4>
                       <h5> ${prods[btn].precio}</h5>`;
     //Le mostramos al usuario que tiene la opcion de quitar el elemento del carrito.
     btn_this.innerHTML="Quitar elemento del carrito.";
     
     father.appendChild(prod);
      
     //Cambiamos la llamada al evento para poder eliminar el elemento del carrito.
    btn_this.onclick=function(){
        deletecOfCart( prod,btn );
    }
}
```

#### deletecOfCart:

```JavaScript
function deletecOfCart( element,btn ){
    let this_btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary")[btn];
    //Eliminamos el elemento de la lista que no se quiere.
    document.getElementById( id_father ).removeChild( element );
    this_btn.innerHTML="añadir al carrito.";
            
    this_btn.onclick=function(){
        addToCart(prods,btn);
    }
}
```

Tambien hice cambios extra:
La clase le coloque los atributo dentro del `constructor`:

```JavaScript
class Producto {
    constructor( id,cantidad,name,precio ){
        this.id=id;
        this.cantidad=cantidad;
        this.name=name;
        this.precio=precio;
    }
}
```

Tambien cambie el operador `let` por `var` para las variables globales.

Agregé los eventos a los botones de clase `btn btn-primary` en JavaScript para darle el trabajo al navegador de ponerle los eventos en vez de hacerlo a mano:

```JavaScript
window.onload=function(){
    //Obtenemos todos los botones de poner al carrito
    let btn=document.getElementsByClassName("btn btn-primary");
    for ( let i=0; i<btn.length; i++ ){
        //Y les ponemos el evento que queremos:
        btn[i].onclick=function(){
            addToCart(prods,i);
        }
    }
    //Iniciamos la variable prods con una lista de la clase Producto();
    prods= arraySet();
}
```

A cosecuencia de esta funcion pude eliminar los eventos del codigo HTML y obtener los mismos resultados.
No me acuerdo que mas hice. Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en dejar un comentario.